# How to check the perfomance for the site in mobile browser using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Please provide me the step of checking the performance and website open in a mobile browser and get the OTP after adding the mobile number.

I want to know the configuration of the mobile with Jmeter and also how to test using mobile OTP for the performance testing

Answer (score 0):

Simulating mobile browser is not a big deal, it can be done by simply sending the relevant [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header via [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager)

When it comes to OTP, if it's received over email you can read it using [Mail Reader Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Mail_Reader_Sampler). However in case of SMS it might be tricky, there are Java libraries like [smppapi](https://smppapi.sourceforge.net/) or [SMSC SMPP simulator](https://github.com/MavoCz/smscsim) so theoretically you can intercept the message, but it would be much easier to ask your applicaiton developers to temporarily turn off the OTP mechanism or provide you a test OTPs you could use

Comment: I get your answer it's usefull to me but the OTP come at SMS when I enter the mobile number and then get that OTP. Can you please give me solution by using jmeter